# Symfony2 javascript url

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

I was using symfony2 and in my javascript file **chooselist.js.twig**, I need to append something to my html page, and I need to get a path of my image. I tried my code like this, but it didn't work.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'listmore',
    data: btnArr,
    success: function(msg){
        var ret = $.parseJSON(msg);                       
        var str="";

        for(var i=0; i<ret.itemTab.length; i++) {
            str +="<a href=\"#\"><li>\
            <p id=\"peopleresume"+jid+"_"+ret.itemTab[i]["pid"]+"\">"+ret.itemTab[i]["pname"]+"</p>\
            <img src=\"{{asset('img/video.png')}}\"/>\
            <div class=\"clear\"></div>\
            <div class=\"listInfo\" id="+ret.itemTab[i]["rid"]+">"+ret.itemTab[i]["introduction"]+"</div>\
            </li></a>";
        }
        tempId.find(".ListBlock").append(str);

    },
    error: function(XmlHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown){
       alert ("failed! "+XmlHttpRequest.responseText);
    }
});
```

in my code {{asset('img/video.png')}}, it doesn't work. What should I do to make it work?

Comment: What means by saying "doesn't work"? What expected as "working" solution?

Comment: my code {{asset('img/video.png')}} would return (http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/My/Test/choose/%7B%7Basset('img/vedio.png')%7D%7D) instead of the path in my web. @Darmen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be **{{ asset('bundles/yourbundle/images/video.png') }}**
Furthermore, make sure you installed your assets by running the following command:

```
php app/console assets:install
```

Comment: well, i put my js files in my web documents, and I have already installed my assets.

Comment: Could you clarify that your js file is a twig file? Did you put it in the js folder in web not in the view folder? I may misunderstood

Comment: My js file is called 'chooselist.js.twig' and it is a twig file in folder 'symfony/web/js/'.Should I put it in a view file?

Comment: Yes your twig files need to be in view folder otherwise the twig parser won't be able to parse the path and etc. After moving that js.twig file to a view folder try to use {% include %} in your main twig file to be parsed and used

Comment: Also if you want to use you js.twig file as **src** in a <script> tag you need to create a routing for that and in controller just render the twig file and return it. In this case your SCRIPT tag will be: `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ path('routing_name_for_js') }}"`. Make sure the pattern in your routing be finished with **.js**

Comment: If you want I can put some example code as new answer to make more sense

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now we come to something, but now it would return '\x2fSymfony\x2fweb\x2fimg\x2fvideo.png'. It is so strange..

Comment: Can I ask to paste the full *asset* command which you used in your js.twig? I guess you may used some specific character